# Combine two files based on a column matching - one of the file's column has the same entries more than once

Tags: perl, r, indexing, matching

I would like to match two files based on one column and combine the matching lines. But one of the files (`file1.txt`) has the same entry more than once. As an example:

file1.txt

```
chr:123 a
chr:123 b
chr:456 a
```

file2.txt

```
chr:123 aa
chr:456 bb
```

I would like to extract the indexes based on the first column.

The final output should look like:

```
chr:123 a aa
chr:123 b aa
chr:456 a bb
```

I tried intersect on R but couldn't figure out how to combine matching lines when `file1.txt` has the same entry more than once.
I am using two for loops but the files are very big and it takes lots of time.

Is there a quicker way to do this in perl or R?

Comment: Take a look at `?merge` and the `all.x=TRUE` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
one <- data.frame(
id=c("chr:123","chr:123","chr:456"),
value=c("a","b","a")
)

two <- data.frame(
id=c("chr:123","chr:456"),
value=c("aa","bb")
)

merge(one,two,by="id",all.x=TRUE)

#result
       id value.x value.y
1 chr:123       a      aa
2 chr:123       b      aa
3 chr:456       a      bb
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) this will save me huge amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:

```
use Modern::Perl;

my %file1Hash;

open my $file1, "<file1.txt" or die $!;
do { my ( $key, $value ) = split; push @{ $file1Hash{$key} }, $value }
  for <$file1>;
close $file1;

open my $file2, "<file2.txt" or die $!;
do {
    my ( $key, $value ) = split;
    do { say "$key $_ $value" for @{ $file1Hash{$key} } } if $file1Hash{$key};
  }
  for <$file2>;
close $file2;
```

Output:

```
chr:123 a aa
chr:123 b aa
chr:456 a bb
```